# Valid value usage in JMeter's JMS Subscriber 'JMS Selector' property - in order to consume messages with a dynamically changing JMSCorrelationID

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-artemis, point-to-point

I have an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis server hosting some queues.
With the help of JMeter JMS Publisher sampler I am publishing a set of messages with some specific property1 and valueX on a queue1 and an app is providing me with response messages to those specific request messages on another queue2 having valueX in the JMSCorrelationId property of the JMS message header. I consume the response message using a JMS Subscriber sampler.

If I just consume the messages'blindly' without using a JMS Selector in the JMS Subscriber sampler I can see in the view results tree (Response Data -> Response Headers) that the consumed messages have the following example property and value:

```
JMSCorrelationId 20240315165957905
```

What I need is to only consume messages with a specific value (which comes from a JMeter variable) in the JMSCorrelationId property from the message header.

I don't understand what value I need to set in the JMS Subscriber property in order to only consume messages having a specific JMSCorrelationId in their header.

I have tried using this in the JMS Selector property of the sampler.

`JMSCorrelationID = '${uniqueID}'`

or

`JMSCorrelationID = 'ID:${uniqueID}'`

and for some reason the JMS Subscriber sampler is not able to find the message even though I see it is in the queue (using the ActiveMQ Artemis Management Console).

Also, I don't know how to debug what static value is used in the selector value by this JMS subscriber sampler because I can't see it generating any logs in the JMeter log file.

Any kind of insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try choosing `Each sample` box under "Setup" in the [JMS Subscriber](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber):

[image]

The values of JMeter variables can be observed in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) if you [increase JMeter logging verbosity to debug level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging).

You can also download or checkout [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter), open the project in your favourite IDE, set the breakpoint in [JMSSampler.browseQueueForConsumption()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/src/protocol/jms/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.java#L328) function and see the actual JMS Selector value.